# What is the Valley of Jehoshaphat?

Tags: joel

> **Joel 3:2** I will gather all nations and bring them down to the Valley of Jehoshaphat. There I will put them on trial for what they did to my inheritance, my people Israel, because they scattered my people among the nations and divided up my land.

What is the Valley of Jehoshaphat? What is the significance of the name Jehoshphat here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the article ["Jehoshaphat, Low Plain Of"](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002384) in the *Insight on the Scriptures*:

> Evidently a symbolic place, also called the “low plain of the decision.” (Joe 3:2, 14) Since it relates to God’s execution of judgment, it is appropriately designated as “the low plain of Jehoshaphat,” for the name Jehoshaphat means “Jehovah Is Judge.” Also, during Jehoshaphat’s reign Jehovah delivered Judah and Jerusalem from the combined forces of Ammon, Moab, and the mountainous region of Seir, causing the enemy forces to become confused and to slaughter one another.​—2Ch 20:1-29.
>
> At the symbolic “low plain of Jehoshaphat” Jehovah judges the nations as worthy of execution on account of their mistreatment of his people. The low plain itself serves as a huge symbolic winepress for crushing the nations like bunches of grapes. To link “the low plain of Jehoshaphat” literally with the Kidron Valley, the Valley of Hinnom, or the Valley of Jezreel, as some have done, is hardly plausible. None of these valleys would be large enough to accommodate “all” the nations.​—Joe 3:1-3, 12-14; compare Re 14:18-20.

Comment: +1 Good answer. You beat me to it :)

Comment: @agarza-I guess this was just before I came back on the scene as I don't remember it. Worth an upvote I think.

Answer (score 3):

Joel 3:2

> I will gather all nations and bring them down to the **Valley of Jehoshaphat**. There I will put them on **trial** for what they did to my inheritance, my people Israel, because they scattered my people among the nations and divided up my land.

the Valley
עֵ֖מֶק (‘ê·meq)
Noun - masculine singular construct
Strong's 6010: A vale

of Jehoshaphat.
יְהֽוֹשָׁפָ֑ט (yə·hō·wō·šā·p̄āṭ)
Noun - proper - masculine singular
Strong's 3092: Jehoshaphat -- '**the LORD has judged**', the name of a number of Israelites

The name Jehoshaphat literally means 'the LORD has judged'. The emphasis of Joel 3:2 is on the trial and judgment on nations.

Comment: +1 I appreciate how you incorporate the original language words and their meanings into your answers.

Answer (score -1):

The Valley of Jehoshaphat is where the kiddron, hinnon and tyropoeon valleys meet just south of the city of David, it is also known as the Valley of Decision.

At the conclusion of Yom Kippur at the end of the 7-year birth pangs starting on Tishri 11 to Tishri 15 (Sukkot), the angles of Hashem will gather the unbelievers in the world and deposit them in this valley. With his word and glory, Hashem will pass judgment on them and kill them, their blood will run bridal deep from this valley down to the reed sea in elat. The birds and vultures will feast on their flesh and bones for several months.